# SSRS report parameter not filtering data

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report with 2 parameters:

1. displays the work week number.
2. is the product hold reason.

Even if I select only one work week, my report displays all work weeks that apply for the second parameter.

Comment: To give you more information, I have 2 chart and 1 table reports in 1 report

Comment: If you want to provide more information then please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29349861/edit) your question and add the information there in order to improve it. I have no idea about SSRS, but I have the feeling that you should provide more information. Do you have some configuration or code that you can provide?

Comment: Are you using filtering in the table or a parameter in the query?
If you're filtering in the Dataset table, what are the filtering expressions? 
If you're filtering in the query, what's the where clause?

Comment: Hannover First, there are other parts of the where clause before this and ,                                                                                                          AND ww.[mfg_ww_no] IN (@mfg_ww_no)

AND 
(

LHH.[reason_comment] LIKE '%REPROBE 8586%' AND 'REPROBE 8586' IN (@HOLD_REASON)
)
OR
(
LHH.[reason_comment] LIKE '%REPROBE LOCKUP%' AND 'REPROBE LOCKUP' IN (@HOLD_REASON)
) 
OR
(------continues like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your **mmf_ww_no** field is only being applied to the first set of criteria:

```
AND ww.[mfg_ww_no] IN (@mfg_ww_no) 
AND 
( LHH.[reason_comment] LIKE '%REPROBE 8586%' AND 'REPROBE 8586' IN (@HOLD_REASON) ) 
OR 
( LHH.[reason_comment] LIKE '%REPROBE LOCKUP%' AND 'REPROBE LOCKUP' IN (@HOLD_REASON) ) 
OR 
(------
```

When it hits the first OR, the rest of the WHERE disregards the **mmf_ww_no** field. To filter all the other criterion, you'd need to use an extra set of parenthesis so the AND applies to all the ORs:

```
AND ww.[mfg_ww_no] IN (@mfg_ww_no) 
AND ( 
( LHH.[reason_comment] LIKE '%REPROBE 8586%' AND 'REPROBE 8586' IN (@HOLD_REASON) ) 
OR 
( LHH.[reason_comment] LIKE '%REPROBE LOCKUP%' AND 'REPROBE LOCKUP' IN (@HOLD_REASON) ) 
OR 
(------
     )
```

Comment: Thanks, That was the issue. my report works fine now